# Replace All With Backwards Direction

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to Replace All With Backwards Direction?

e.g.
Text:

```
Reactive Patterns with RxJS.
A practical guide.
```

Cursor is at the beginning of line 2.
i.e. just before the character "A".
Replace All " " With "_" Backwards Direction.

Text becomes:

```
Reactive_Patterns_with_RxJS.
A practical guide.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily with an extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).  With this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",                      // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": "cursorUp",   // move cursor up a line

    "find": "(\\s)",
    
    "replace": "_",
    
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "line",        // only do current line find
    "postCommands": "cursorDown"   // put cursor back where it was
  },
  // "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
},
```

[image: demo of cursorUp find and replace]

[Or it could be made into a setting with a command if you wish.]

Comment: This is ok.
Is there another way?
e.g. 
Notepad++ has a “Backwards direction” checkbox which can be checked.

Comment: There is no similar `backwards` functionality in vscode.  Perhaps another extension has implemented it - I don't know.